# Marionette.js - ItemView get parent Region reference

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Marionette.js `Regions` have a `close` event, where they can tell if they themselves closed one of their child views in one of the `Regions`.

The problem I am having, is that this `close` event does not trigger if the child view calls close on itself.

See the following:

```
var SubView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

  // suppose close is called from the region item itself...
  internalClose: function() {
    this.close();
  },
});

var Layout = Marionette.Layout.extend({

  template: '<div class="region1"></div>',

  regions: {
    region1: '.region1',
  },

  onRender: function() {

    this.region1.show(new SubView());
    // When the SubView calls its own close, 
    // region1 does not register a close event.

    this.region1.on('close', function() {
      // self destruct or something exciting...
    });
  },
});
```

How do I get the `ItemView` to communicate to the Layout, and tell it that it closed itself (such as by hitting an exit button in the `ItemView` or something). I need the `Layout` to manipulate addition DOM of its own when the `ItemView` closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a listener to the region's `show` event and listen to the current view's `close` event:

```
var region = this.region1;

region.on('show', function() {
    region.currentView.on('close', function() {
        // this message will cause the layout to self destruct...
     });
     // NOTE: You won't have to clean up this event listener since calling 
     //       close on either the region or the view will do it for you.
});
```

You can probably do this in lieu of listening for `close` on the region since that just signals the closing of the `currentView`.

Comment: I didn't know about currentView, this did it for me. Thanks!